# Random Story button tries to generate story 1-1000

Tags: javascript, php, html

I've changed my code to only use one javascript file and one php file

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Stories - USA</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/country.css">
</head>
<body data-country="usa">
  <header>
      <h1>Stories</h1>
      <h3>United States of America</h3>
  </header>
    <main>
      <div id="content-wrapper">
        <div id="get-container">
          <input type="text" id="story-number" placeholder="Enter story number">
          <button id="get" type="button">Get Story</button>
          <button id="getRandom" type="button">Random Story</button>
        </div>
        <div id="story-container">
          <!-- Story content will be displayed here -->
          <div id="generated-text"></div>
          <button id="back" type="button">Back</button>
        </div>
    </main>
    <script src="Scripts/country.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**country.js**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var storyContainer = document.getElementById('story-container');
    var storyNumberInput = document.getElementById('story-number');
    var getButton = document.getElementById('get');
    var getRandomButton = document.getElementById('getRandom');
    var clearButton = document.getElementById('back');

    // Determine the country from the URL
    var country = getCountryFromURL();

    function getCountryFromURL() {
        var url = window.location.href;
        if (url.includes('united-states-of-america.html')) {
            return 'usa';
        } else if (url.includes('sweden.html')) {
            return 'sweden';
        } else {
            return 'argentina';
        }
        // Add more countries here
    }

    // Define an object to map countries to their text files and actual total stories
    var countryData = {
        'argentina': {
            file: 'argentina.txt',
            actualTotalStories: 3 // Update this based on your actual stories
        },
        'usa': {
            file: 'usa.txt',
            actualTotalStories: 1000 // Update this based on your actual stories
        },
        'sweden': {
            file: 'sweden.txt',
            actualTotalStories: 5 // Update this based on your actual stories
        },
        // Add more countries as needed
    };

    function clearStoryContainer() {
        if (storyContainer) {
            storyContainer.style.display = 'none';
            var generatedTextElement = document.getElementById('generated-text');
            if (generatedTextElement) {
                generatedTextElement.innerHTML = '';
            }
            storyNumberInput.value = '';
            clearButton.style.display = 'none';
            storyContainer.scrollTop = 0;
        }
    }

    function fetchStory(country, storyNumber) {
        clearStoryContainer();

        if (storyNumber === '0') {
            // Generate a random story number between 1 and totalStories for the selected country
            var randomStoryNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * countryData[country].actualTotalStories) + 1;
            storyNumber = randomStoryNumber;
        }

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'PHP/router.php?country=' + encodeURIComponent(country) + '&story=' + encodeURIComponent(storyNumber), true);

        xhr.onload = function () {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                var generatedText = xhr.responseText;
                if (storyContainer) {
                    storyContainer.style.display = 'block';
                    var generatedTextElement = document.getElementById('generated-text');
                    if (generatedTextElement) {
                        generatedTextElement.innerHTML = parseAndStyleTitles(generatedText);
                    }
                    clearButton.style.display = 'inline-block';
                    storyContainer.scrollTop = 0;
                }
            } else {
                console.log('Error fetching story. Status code: ' + xhr.status);
                clearStoryContainer();
                if (xhr.status === 404) {
                    displayErrorMessage('The story file does not exist.');
                } else {
                    displayErrorMessage('Error fetching story.');
                }
            }
        };
        xhr.onerror = function () {
            console.log('Network error while fetching story.');
            clearStoryContainer();
            displayErrorMessage('Network error while fetching story.');
        };
        xhr.send();
    }

    function displayErrorMessage(errorMessage) {
        if (storyContainer) {
            storyContainer.style.display = 'block';
        }
        var generatedTextElement = document.getElementById('generated-text');
        if (generatedTextElement) {
            generatedTextElement.innerHTML = errorMessage;
        }
    }

    function parseAndStyleTitles(text) {
        return text.replace(/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/g, function (match, title) {
            return '<span>' + title + '</span>';
        });
    }

    if (getButton) {
        getButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
            var storyNumber = storyNumberInput.value;
            fetchStory(country, storyNumber);
        });
    }

    if (getRandomButton) {
        getRandomButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
            fetchStory(country, '0');
        });
    }

    if (clearButton) {
        clearButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
            clearStoryContainer();
        });
    }
});
```

**router.php**

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['country'])) {
    $country = $_GET['country'];
    $storyNumber = $_GET['story'];

    // Define an array of valid countries and their corresponding text files
    $validCountries = array(
        'argentina' => 'argentina.txt',
        'usa' => 'usa.txt',
        'sweden' => 'sweden.txt',
        // Add more countries and their text files as needed
    );

    if (isset($validCountries[$country])) {
        $file = '../../Stories/' . $validCountries[$country];
    } else {
        // Return an error if the requested country does not exist
        echo 'The requested country does not exist.';
        exit;
    }

    if (file_exists($file)) {
        // Read the content of the text file
        $fileContent = file_get_contents($file);

        // Split the content into stories based on the delimiter
        $stories = preg_split('/<!-- Unique delimiter separating stories -->/', $fileContent);

        // Determine the actual number of stories
        $actualTotalStories = count($stories);

        if ($storyNumber === '0') {
            // Generate a random story number within the range of actual stories
            $storyNumber = rand(1, $actualTotalStories);
        } else {
            $storyNumber = intval($storyNumber);
        }

        if ($storyNumber >= 1 && $storyNumber <= $actualTotalStories) {
            // Check if the requested story exists
            $requestedStory = trim($stories[$storyNumber - 1]);

            // Replace "\r\n\r\n" with "<br><br>" for paragraphs
            $formattedStory = str_replace("\r\n\r\n", "<br><br>", $requestedStory);

            // Replace remaining "\r\n" with "<br>" for line breaks within paragraphs
            $formattedStory = str_replace("\r\n", "<br>", $formattedStory);

            echo $formattedStory;
        } else {
            // Return an error if the requested story does not exist
            echo 'The requested story does not exist.';
        }
    } else {
        // Return an error if the story file does not exist
        echo 'The story file does not exist.';
    }
} else {
    // Return an error for an invalid request
    echo 'Invalid request.';
}

?>
```

Using the "Get Story" button works just fine, but when I use the "Random Story" button it tries to fetch story 1-1000 even tho I only have 6 stories in the usa.txt so far.

When I have 6 stories in the text file I want it to fetch 1-6 until I add story 7 then I want it to fetch 1-7. But I do want to keep the "actualTotalStories: 1000" as that's the max amount of stories I will ever reach.

Comment: Why specify the story number in the JavaScript?  You could just let PHP return a random story, based on the number of stories available

Comment: How can I modify my codes to get this to work?

Comment: you could make argentina.html a PHP page (argentina.php) and perform in there the preg_split to get $actualTotalStories. Once you have that, you can print the total value as a data-attribute on your input, something like `<input type="text" id="story-number" placeholder="Enter story number" data-total="<?php echo $actualTotalStories; ?>">` and then use that in javascript in place of `var totalStories = 1000;`

Comment: But what if I want it as argentina.html, but change the argentina.js and argentina.php to make it work?

Comment: if you want to keep it a simple html file, you have to setup a separate php page which performs the total count (for example, `getArgentinaTotalStories.php`) and call that via ajax from your javascript.

Comment: yes, I do have argentina.php, but how do I modify the js and php file for this to work?

Comment: Your random button does not need to determine any story number at all. Just send a request to your PHP script, that lets you realize that no specific story was requested (for example by sending `story=0`, or leaving that parameter out altogether) - and then simply have your PHP script select a random story out of all records in the data set.

Comment: I get what you mean, but I'm not sure how I should change the codes to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

**Please note:** This has been the correct (and later accepted) answer to the question as it was at the time this answer was written. The question has been edited since to be an entire different question and this answer has been un-accepted. See edit history of the question for details.

---

You could change **argentina.php** as follows:

```
<?php    
// Read the content of argentina.txt (relative to the location of this PHP file)
$storiesFile = file_get_contents('../../Stories/argentina.txt');

// Split the content into stories based on the unique delimiter (<!-- Unique delimiter separating stories -->)
$stories = preg_split('/<!-- Unique delimiter separating stories -->/', $storiesFile);

// Determine the actual number of stories
$actualTotalStories = count($stories);

// Read the requested story number from the URL parameter
$storyNumber = (isset($_GET['story']) && $_GET['story']!='0') ? $_GET['story'] : rand(1, $actualTotalStories);

if ($storyNumber >= 1 && $storyNumber <= $actualTotalStories) {
    // Check if the requested story exists
    $requestedStory = trim($stories[$storyNumber - 1]);
    $formattedStory = nl2br($requestedStory);
    echo $formattedStory;
} else {
    echo 'Error: Story not found.';
}
```

This is going to return the story requested but a random story if the URL parameter *story* is missing.

**Code update**: Random story returned if parameter if missing **or** 0. Thanks to CBroe!

Comment: That works for "Get Story" button, but when I press "Random Story" I get this message: "Error: Story not found." because it tries to load any number between 1-1000

Comment: Because it's random only if you **do not** submit the story parameter at all.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "story parameter" I'd like to know how I can get it to pick a story randomly.

Comment: I've updated my answer so it also returns a random story if the story requested is 0.  So you could simply use `fetchStory('0');` instead of `fetchStory(randomStoryNumber);`  in `getRandomButton.addEventListener('click'`.

Comment: So what part of the code do I have to replace with what?

Comment: Inside the JS replace `fetchStory(randomStoryNumber);` with `fetchStory('0');`

Comment: And now you could also remove the line `var randomStoryNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * totalStories) + 1;` above the line changed, because the random number ist not needed anymore.

Comment: In the file argentina.html the buttons looks fine when I press them, but in usa.html it appears like the buttons and the textbox "jumps" a little bit, both html files uses the same CSS file, so not sure what the issue is.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the original question, right? Feel free to ask a new question and link it here in the comments. I'll be happy to take a look at it.

Comment: Alright, I made a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77280891/the-buttons-and-the-textbox-is-jumping-to-the-right

Comment: I've updated this question, as it's the same problem but I changed from having 1 js and php file per country to just using 1 for all of them.

Comment: Sorry @PatrikQvarnström, changing your question and un-accept an answer is not how SO is supposed to be used. That's just rude. Also: If you actually **understood** answers instead of just copy & paste them, you could still solve the new problem using my old answer.

Comment: I just don't know much about coding this stuff, which makes it hard for me to understand the answers, I just want to get this to work. Not my intention at all to appear as being rude, sorry for that.